# Deduplicate Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, duplicates

Implement an iterator(Generic) which skips next element if it is equal to last printed element.
e.g : AAABBCCCCD
On complete iteration will print ABCD.

Below is my attempt. Please suggest if it can be done in a better way.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DeDupIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

E next = null;
Iterator<E> itr;

public DeDupIterator(Iterator<E> iter) {
    itr = iter;
    next = itr.next();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(itr.hasNext())
    if (next != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public E next() {
    E item=null;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        item = (E) itr.next();
        if (!item.equals(next)) {
            E temp = next;
            next = item;
            return temp;
        }

    }
    next = item;
    return next;

    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Please suggest if it can be done in a better way*" if your code is working and you are asking for review then your question should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oops. My bad!
I will paste it there.

Comment: In that case don't forget to delete this question :)

Comment: I see at least two bugs in this code. Are you sure it works correctly? What if the collection is empty? and itr.hasNext() returns false from the beginning. What if the collection is one element long? DeDupIterator.hasNext() will return false instead of true, won't it?

Comment: @ciamej Yes it throws an exception for empty collection and doesn't print anything for single element. I will try to fix it.

Comment: @Pshemo Now clearly my code has bugs, I think I shall wait for an answer here :).

Comment: As I said "if your code is working". In that case you should remove your question from codereview since this site is only for working code examples.

Comment: @Pshemo Ok deleting it from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question without actually writing the code for you.

I'll just focus on main issues with this code:

- it doesn't work for empty collections, because it calls `itr.next()` unconditionally in the constructor, which leads to an exception
- it doesn't work for a single element collections, because `hasNext()` returns `false` instead of `true` - this is because you call `itr.next()` in the constructor and then in `hasNext()` you first check `itr.hasNext()`
- `remove()` is completely wrong, because `itr.next()` was called earlier
- it should throw `NoSuchElementException` in `next()` if there is no element to return, but it doesn't

**How to fix it?**

I would start by removing `itr.next()` from constructor as it's messing many things up.

Then you have to somehow distinguish between two cases: when `itr.next()` was called in advance or not. E.g. add a `boolean` field to facilitate that.

You will have to call `itr.next()` in advance if `hasNext()` is called.

Also you should be prepared that `itr.next()` returns `null` as a completely valid value that can be stored in a collection. You should not rely on `next` to be not `null`. For this reason you should have one more `boolean` that determines whether your `next` field actually holds a value or is empty.

The `remove()` method should probably remove all the duplicates and not only one element. If you find it too demanding to implement you can always throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. If you decide to implement it, remember to throw `IllegalStateException` if `next()` has not yet been called, or `remove()` has already been called after the last `next()` call

This should be enough for you to get the right solution yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Really nice answer, you should consider spending some time on Code Review.... [this question was cross-posted there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49778/deduplicate-iterator), and your answer here would be great there.... and there's a good chat room too [the 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)